# is_404() - where does this get set?

Tags: wp-query, 404-error

Where does `is_404()` get set?

Looking at the source in query.php:

```
function is_404() {
    global $wp_query;

    if ( ! isset( $wp_query ) ) {
        _doing_it_wrong( __FUNCTION__, __( 'Conditional query tags do not work before the query is run. Before then, they always return false.' ), '3.1' );
        return false;
    }

    return $wp_query->is_404();
}
```

which just returns a value already set in $wp_query.

However, if I then set a breakpoint in `set_query_var` this never gets hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a dedicated method for it `WP_Query->set_404()`. From quick search through code it can be set in `WP_Query->parse_query()` or `WP->handle_404()` (note `WP`, not `WP_Query`!).

But it can (and sometimes does) get set on query externally, for example by plugin that needs to invalidate specific resource.